# Authentication Header for HTML Post form

Tags: forms, jwt, http-headers, access-token

Is it possible to parse/add an authentication on the submit from a standard HTML for? E.g. I'm using oAuth to authentication logged-in users, and have a usecase where I need to use a standard HTML form with the action and method attributes. But I can't seem to find a way to parse the JWT Token I'm using for authentication. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do it with a regular HTML form. If you need to add an `Authorization` header to the request, the only thing you can do is to make a request from the Javascript (as is shown in Subhashis's answer). It doesn't have to be jQuery though, you can use plain JS and fetch or some libraries for making http calls (e.g. axios). Whichever you use, remember that it will be an AJAX call, so your JS will have to handle the response properly (the response will not be handled by the browser automatically).

Comment: Thanks you. I have tried using nativa JS fetch, but on POST request this don't work from safari browser... Or at least not on iPhone. It works fine from chrome/firefox though. So setting auth headers with fetch works fine in some browser but not on all it seems. Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: You can check which features you can use in browsers on caniuse.com, e.g. fetch: https://caniuse.com/?search=fetch it seems that fetch should work on iPhone as well. This must be some other issues with Safari.

Answer (score 1):

You may use JQuery form submit to send authorization header

```
var form = $('#form-id').get(0); 
var formData = new FormData(form);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "url");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "jwt token");
xhr.send(formData);
```